# How to access queryParams in ember when locationType is set to hash

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm unable to access ember queryParams when the locationType in the environment.js file set to hash. Below is how my controller and route are setup

```
    //controllers/application.js
    export default Ember.Controller.extend({
       queryParams:['qp1','qp2']
   });

   //routes/application.js
    model : function(params) {
       console.log('queryParams1': +params.qp1);
       console.log('queryParams2': +params.qp2);
    }
```

My url is something like https://www.test.com/?qp1=10&qp2=20

Output when locationType is set to auto

queryParams1: 10; queryParams2: 20

Output when locationType is set to hash

queryParams1: undefined; queryParams2: undefined

I'm wondering why I'm able to access queryParams when the locationType is auto but not when locationType is hash

Comment: if possible provide all the related code, like how you defined it in route.js file. It should work fine , i am using queryParams with locationType set to hash

Comment: @kumkanillam: I've updated my question to give more info. Please let me know if anything else is required